# Google API - get locations with Google_Service_MyBusinessBusinessInformation

Tags: php, google-api-php-client

with disabling old my_business api (v4), i can't get location. I'am using :

```
$my_business_account = new Google_Service_MyBusinessAccountManagement($client);
$list_accounts_response = $my_business_account->accounts->listAccounts();
$account = $list_accounts_response[0];
$mybusinessService = new Google_Service_MyBusinessBusinessInformation($client);
$locations = $mybusinessService->accounts_locations;
$queryParams = [
    "pageSize" => 10,
    'readMask' => "user.display_name,photo"
];
$locationsList = $locations->listAccountsLocations($account->name, $queryParams);
```

I'm still getting a 400 response:

```
    Google\Service\Exception #400
{
  "error": {
    "code": 400,
    "message": "Request contains an invalid argument.",
    "status": "INVALID_ARGUMENT",
    "details": [
      {
        "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.BadRequest",
        "fieldViolations": [
          {
            "field": "read_mask",
            "description": "Invalid field mask provided"
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

In the API documentation https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/accounts.locations/list

the readMask field is kept mandatory, but unfortunately I do not know the write format for the PHP API client, or for REST (eg POSTMAN).
Will anyone help?

Answer (score 4):

My fault, using readMask fields must be from Location attributes (https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations), eg. name, websiteUri etc.
Maybe it helps somebody.

Comment: Have you been able to get mix of the old v4.9 and the new v1 API working? E.g. using older endpoints that haven't been replaced? Or do you just need endpoints already available under v1 API?

Comment: @Ondra ...you should actually paste a snippet of how to form the read mask as it would be helpful instead of just a doc link

Answer (score 0):

To give more details on this answer, the **readMask** field is a required attribute, so be sure to not omit it. Also, the possible values for it are listed on the Locations docs page, under the *fields* table column: https://developers.google.com/my-business/reference/businessinformation/rest/v1/locations

In my case, I used the following value of the **readMask** attribute, but you can modify this and add your own fields if you wish:

```
$queryParams['readMask'] = 'name,storefrontAddress,title,languageCode';
```